# How to auto-extend the data with the MSB aligned?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am now trying to create a "print" in Verilog to help me debug.

When assigning a short string to a long buffer.

For example:

```
reg[63:0] buf;

task print(input[63:0] in);
begin
  buf<=in;
end
endtask

print("Hello");
```

The data in the buffer will be `/0/0/0Hello`

It will take many clocks or a big area to deal with the `/0`

As the string is determined before the synthesis. Is there any elegant way to align the data in the MSB direction? I wish the data will look like `Hello/0/0/0`.

Or `/0/0/0olleH' is also OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The streaming operator is MSB/left aligned

```
print( {>>{"hello"}} ); // Hello/0/0/0
```

Comment: I am now using a macro to do it. Thanks for your help.  `define print(a,b) int_print({>>{a}},b)